# Copy multiple values into certain cells on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i'm having trouble in copying values from one sheet to another sheet using Google script. When I call the function, it says

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.**

So it doesn't execute.

```
function BalanceLifeTodayUpdate() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!IC702','\'All Links\'!IC703','\'All Links\'!IC707','\'All Links\'!IC708').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Balance Life Today\'!C404','\'Balance Life Today\'!C405','\'Balance Life Today\'!C409','\'Balance Life Today\'!C410'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`getRange` of Class Spreadsheet is `getRange(a1Notation)`. In your script, 2nd argument is not required to be used. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In your script, how about merging the cells of `'\'All Links\'!IC702','\'All Links\'!IC703'` and also `'\'Balance Life Today\'!C404','\'Balance Life Today\'!C405'`? The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!IC702:IC703').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Balance Life Today\'!C404:C405'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

or

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!IC702:IC703').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Balance Life Today\'!C404'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String))

### Added:

From your following reply,

> but I have more cells to be copied. For example: 'var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); spreadsheet.getRange(''All Links'!IC702',''All Links'!IC703',''All Links'!IC707',''All Links'!IC708').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange(''Balance Life Today'!C404',''Balance Life Today'!C405',''Balance Life Today'!C409',''Balance Life Today'!C410'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); };'

When there are only 2 pairs of source and destination ranges, I thought that the loop can be used. So, how about the following modification? If your ranges are more existing, in order to reduce the process cost, Sheets API might be suitable.

#### Sample script:

```js
function BalanceLifeTodayUpdate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // This is from your updated script.
  var ranges = [
    { src: '\'All Links\'!IC702:IC703', dst: '\'Balance Life Today\'!C404' },
    { src: '\'All Links\'!IC707:IC708', dst: '\'Balance Life Today\'!C409' }
  ];

  ranges.forEach(({ src, dst }) => {
    spreadsheet.getRange(src).copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange(dst), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks but I have more cells to be copied. For example:
       'var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!IC702','\'All Links\'!IC703','\'All Links\'!IC707','\'All Links\'!IC708').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Balance Life Today\'!C404','\'Balance Life Today\'!C405','\'Balance Life Today\'!C409','\'Balance Life Today\'!C410'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};'

Comment: @Sohel Ahamed Thank you for replying. In your showing script, you are using the ranges of `'\'All Links\'!IC702','\'All Links\'!IC703'` and `'\'Balance Life Today\'!C404','\'Balance Life Today\'!C405'`. My answeer is for removing your issue of `Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature`. But from your reply, it seems that the more ranges are used. But, from `but I have more cells to be copied. For example: ,,,`, I cannot notice whether you are using more other ranges. I'm worried that there might be more hidden ranges. Can you provide your correct question?

Comment: Extramly sorry making confusion. I've updated the original question.

Comment: @Sohel Ahamed For your updated script, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?